# How do I wait for an async function to finish executing before rendering a widget in Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, async-await

On my `main.dart` file, I want to check if a user is logged so as to direct him to the appropriate screen. I am using SharedPrefence to store user detail from Firebase.
How do I tell my function to wait until my SharedPreference async function finishes executing before it can render the appropriate widget.

Below is my code:

```
  Widget _gotoHomeScreen() {
  AuthService.getuserPrefEmail().then((email) {
  print(email);
  AuthService.email = email;
  if (email == null) {
    return LoginScreen();
  } else {
    AuthService.uid = email;
    return HomeMenuScreen();
  }
});
```

}

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You don't have to wait for the build, you should build something, to show to the user that the app is loading something (or a blank screen), and then rebuild when the funcion ends.

You could have a Widget variable that is set to a default when you create the widget, say with a `CircularProgressIndicator`, then change it with setState, something like this:

```
class YourWidgetState extends State<YourWidget> {
  Widget _body = CircularProgressIndicator();  // Default Body

  @override
  void initState(){
    _gotoHomeScreen();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context){
    return _body;
  }

  Widget _gotoHomeScreen() {
    AuthService.getuserPrefEmail().then((email){
      AuthService.email = email;
      if (email == null) {
        setState(() => _body = LoginScreen());
      } else {
        AuthService.uid = email;
        setState(() => _body = HomeMenuScreen());
      }
    });
  }
}
```

---

**Another way** would be to use a variable to inform you about the loading situation, like `bool finishedLoading`, and call `setState` to change the value when it's done, using the `email` variable you set to know when the user is logged in, and do a conditional build, like this:

```
bool loading = true;

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context){
  if(loading) return CircularProgressIndicator();

  if(AuthService.email == null)
    return LoginScreen();
  else
    return HomeMenuScreen();
}

Widget _gotoHomeScreen() {
  AuthService.getuserPrefEmail().then((email){
    AuthService.email = email;
    if (email != null) {
     AuthService.uid = email;
    }
    setState((){ loading = false; });
  });
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Use a simple FutureBuilder!

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html

```
FutureBuilder<Email>(
future: AuthService.getuserPrefEmail(),
 builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<String> snapshot) {
  switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
    case ConnectionState.active:
    case ConnectionState.waiting:
     return CircularProgressIndicator();
    case ConnectionState.done:
     if (snapshot.hasError) {
       return Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}');
      }
     .... here route to your screen or set it how you want
  }
 },
)
```