# Flutter, provider and a Future async function (http post request)

Tags: flutter, flutter-provider, flutter-future

i am trying to call an (Future) *http* post request in a
**ChangeNotifier** class. That means, after the Future is completed, the notifyListeners() should be called (see example below).

No matter, what I tried, in the
**ChangeNotifier - App_State_Controller class**,
the function **callAPI** executes its functions
not in the correct order, waiting for the API request
(despite the await keyword)
and then executing the setText and therefore notifyListeners()
(I also used the a combination using futureFunction.then((){})).

In a previous [answer on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58728607/how-do-i-wait-for-an-async-function-to-finish-executing-before-rendering-a-widge)
it is suggested to either set the state of a stateful widget
or use a FutureBuilder.
In principle, the setText(text) notifyListeners() updates *many
widgets*.

Do you have any idea how to solve this problem if possible
within the *ChangeNotifier class?*?

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';


Future<Map> getHttpPost(String httpURL,String text) async {
  // According to //https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/networking/fetch-data
  final http.Response response = await http.post(
      Uri.parse(httpURL),
      headers: <String, String>{
        'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
      },
      body: jsonEncode(<String, String>{
        "information_text"  : text,
      }
      ));
  if(response.body.isNotEmpty) {
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      return json.decode(response.body);
    } else {
      return {};
    }
  }else{
    return {};
  }
}

class App_State_Controller extends ChangeNotifier {
  Map AnalysisResults                   = {"text":"defaulttext"};
  String anotherStringVariable          = "";

  Future<void> callAPI (String token,String text) async {
    AnalysisResults = await getHttpPost(token, text);
    // The problem is here: Instead of waiting for the
    // AnalysisResults to arrive, it calls setText and
    // activates the notifyListener with an OLDER TEXT!
    setText(AnalysisResults["text"]);
  }

  void setText(String new_text) {
    anotherStringVariable = new_text;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

Comment: Does your server return (response.body) what you expect it to be? Is text updated?

Comment: Yes, everything is as expected. At the moment, the main problem is, that the state in ChangeNotifierProvider is updated too late - after notifyListener ist called

Comment: Please add your widget code.